# element length resizes (selenium, python)

Tags: python, selenium

I'm currently trying to iterate through a feed of clickable items and click them one by one and also scroll down to get new items in view range. The problem is, that I'm clicking the items, based on the length of presence_of_all_elements_located(which I assign to a variable called elem) . When recalling that function, the size of elem keeps increasing till a specific point (about 60 most of the time) and then starts to decrease a little and then it keeps resizing in a range between 40 and 60 even when loading new content. The problem is that I can't click every single element, because at the point of resizing the counter variable I got is not pointing to the next element anymore, but some element at the end of the newly loaded elements. This way I skip many elements. I tried to explain it as best as I can, if you got any questions, just ask. Thanks in advance.

I've tried adjusting my counter variable to the new resizing, but since the resizing keeps to vary I can't fix it this way

Here's the code I'm using:

```py
        # iterate through displayed feed


        #load all so far reachable elements once
        self.elem = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "classnamehere")))



        print("elem1 length: " + str(len(self.elem)))

        if self.scroll_position < len(self.elem) - 1:
            self.scroll_position += 1
        else:
            pass

        #scroll to picture we want to click on
        actions = ActionChains(self.driver)
        if self.scroll_position < len(self.elem):
            actions.move_to_element(self.elem[self.scroll_position]).perform()


        self.elem[self.scroll_position].click()
```

Comment: Can you share url?

Comment: @Sers unfortunately not :( but you can think of it kinda like instagram when you search for a hashtag and scroll through the displayed items

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple solution.

```
elems = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "classnamehere")))
for ele in elems:
    # this will scroll the element into view
    ele.location_once_scrolled_into_view
    # click on the element
    ele.click()
    # if .click() not worked then comment that above line and use below line
    #driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",ele)
```